# avoid extra page for a footnote when a paragraph is split by afterpage

Tags: footnotes, page-breaking, bigfoot, afterpage

I have a document where text should float around a landscape page that I insert with `\afterpage{}`. If (as is the case for me) a paragraph is 'broken' by afterpage (i.e. the paragraph starts before the landscape page and ends after) and at the same time there is a footnote, then that footnote goes onto an otherwise empty page all by its own.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{afterpage} %for landscape pages with text floating around
\usepackage{pdflscape}     %for landscape pages
\usepackage{bigfoot}        % for better footnotes
\usepackage{lipsum}            % for testing
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-4]

    \afterpage{
        \begin{landscape}

        It doesn't matter what I put here. 

        \end{landscape}
    \clearpage
}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.\footnote{This is a footnote to a paragraph that starts on the page before afterpage and ends after the afterpage. The footnote should be on the page after, but instead it goes on an extra page. }

\lipsum[7-8]    

\end{document}
```

Desired behavior: The footnote on what is page 2 when you compile the example should be on what is currently page 4. This should of course eliminate page 2 so that there are only three pages in total (i.e. the footnote would then be on page 3).

Not a solution: I know I could break the concerned paragraph in two, but I prefer to avoid doing so. It is a connected piece of information and a break would be artificial. Same for moving around text since I have footnotes all over.

Comment: The documentation for `afterpage` does say: **This is really a pre-release, to see whether people like the idea of a command like this. This implementation is _not_ particularly robust. This implementation does not work in two column mode, and can get `confused' by \LaTeX's floating environments.**

Comment: actually afterpage has code to cope with normal footnotes and if you comment out `\usepackage{bigfoot}` then it does the right thing. `bigfoot` appears to be using `\marks` rather than footnote insertions to encode footnotes and afterpage wasn't expecting that,

Comment: @JohnKormylo are bigfoot footnotes floats? that would explain things, although normal footnotes are not floats I had a quick look at bigfoot code and the footnotes seem to be \inserts like normal footnotes

Comment: @DavidCarlisle indeed it works without bigfoot, however I need it in other places. I had thought to work around by redefining the regular footnote via `\newcommand{\oldfootnote}{\footnote}` before calling `\usepackage{bigfoot}` but that still gives the undesired result. Then I'm not familiar with defining my own commands so I might be overlooking stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a perfect solution, but it works here.  Now the question is why the big empty space at the bottom of page 3?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{afterpage} %for landscape pages with text floating around
\usepackage{pdflscape}     %for landscape pages
\let\oldoutput\output
\usepackage{bigfoot}        % for better footnotes
\let\newoutput\output
\usepackage{lipsum}            % for testing
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-4]
    \afterpage{\let\clearpage\newpage
       \begin{landscape}

        It doesn't matter what I put here. 

        \end{landscape}
}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
\footnote{This is a footnote to a paragraph that starts on the page before afterpage and ends after the afterpage. The footnote should be on the page after, but instead it goes on an extra page. }

\lipsum[7-8]    

\end{document}
```

---

The above demonstrates the role of `\clearpage` and `\output` in the problem.  This solution puts `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` in different paragraphs.  `\afterpage` executes after the first paragraph is formatted but before the end is printed.  This should work in general, although it is only needed in cases like this.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{afterpage} %for landscape pages with text floating around
\usepackage{pdflscape}     %for landscape pages
\usepackage{bigfoot}        % for better footnotes
\usepackage{lipsum}            % for testing
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-4]
    \afterpage{%
       \begin{landscape}

        It doesn't matter what I put here. 

        \end{landscape}
}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
\footnotemark

\hrule height0pt% removes gap
\footnotetext{This is a footnote to a paragraph that starts on the page before afterpage and ends after the afterpage. The footnote should be on the page after, but instead it goes on an extra page. }

\lipsum[7-9]    

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 it does solve the problem but I am afraid the spacing between paragraphs is a big issue so it is not a practical solution. Still, would you mind explaining what these two lines do, or point me to a resource? Thanks!

Comment: I was playing with this for several hours trying to save and restore the footnote, with no luck whatsoever.  The footnote is stored in \footins and \NF@savebox, but every time I check they are empty.  I was able to remove the extra page using \let\output=\oldoutput, but lost the footnote pemanently.

Comment: For references I use source2e.pdf from CTAN and the TeXbook by Knuth.  And of course bigfoot.sty.